# Convert each row in a PySpark DataFrame to a file in s3

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark and I need to convert each row in a DataFrame to a JSON file (in s3), preferably naming the file using the value of a selected column.

Couldn't find how to do that. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think directly we can't store for each row as a JSON based file. Instead of that we can do like iterate for each partition of `dataframe` and connect to S3 using AWS S3 based library's (to connect to S3 on the partition level). Then, On each partition with the help of iterator, we can convert the row into JSON based file and push to S3.